# Hotlinking facebook profile pictures

Tags: facebook, graph, image

I want to know if I can hotlink facebook profile pictures for every who signup to website using facebook connect?

Facebook allow get users profile picture using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[ID]/picture?type=square
```

but is hot-linking of profile picture is allowed or not otherwise I will have to cache them on my own server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no issue using that link directly in an `img` tag as the `src`.

Comment: It does not work for me, the image doesn't load. I am using firefox.